# Change line spacing in text boxes

Tags: vba, ms-word, textbox

I am relatively new to Word VBA. How do I in Word vba change the format of a filled text box from double space to single space? I have tried:

```
Sub ChangeTextbox

    Dim shp As Shape

    For Each shp In ActiveDocument.Shapes
        If shp.Type = msoTextBox Then
                shp.TextFrame.TextRange.ParagraphFormat.LineSpacingRule = wdLineSpaceSingle
                shp.TextFrame.TextRange.ParagraphFormat.SpaceAfter = 0
        End If
    Next
end sub
```

Neither `paragraphformat` property is accepted or changed.

Comment: Are you getting an error? The `shp.TextFrame.TextRange.ParagraphFormat.LineSpacingRule = wdLineSpaceSingle` works for me.

Comment: The 'correct' way to do this is by using an appropriately-defined Style. Be that as it may, your posted code does work. Are you sure the content is in a textbox, not a table, for example?

Comment: Are you sure what you call "text box" is the type of text box being addressed in the code? Word has a number of things that can be called "text box"... How were these text boxes created? Or, another way to look at it: if you add a line `shp.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "test"` does that execute?